# How to allow a file to be read by multiple users/process at a time on web server

Tags: c#-4.0, runtime-error, audio-streaming, asp.net-web-api2

I am using below code in asp.net webapi for audio streaming to allow android application to call api and play songs.

```
 public class AudioController : ApiController
    {
       ITrackRepository _TrackRepo = new TrackRepository();

        public AudioController()
        {

        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
        {
            var trackd = _TrackRepo.GetPlayfilepath(id);

            string filename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(trackd.Select(x => x.FilePath).FirstOrDefault());

            var audio = new AudioStream(filename);
            string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);

            var response = Request.CreateResponse();
            response.Content = new PushStreamContent(audio.WriteToStream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/" + fileExtension));              
            return response;
        }

    }



 public class AudioStream 
    {
        private readonly string _filename;

        public AudioStream(string filename)
        {

            _filename = filename;
        }

        public async void WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var buffer = new byte[65536];

                using (var video = File.Open(_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var length = (int)video.Length;
                    var bytesRead = 1;

                    while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));
                        await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        length -= bytesRead;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (HttpException ex)
            {
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                outputStream.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

I am able to play song, i tested it with vlc (stream) and its working fine, Issue is when i try to play same song in parallel in another player its giving me below error

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

I completely understand error, but i am not able to find any satisfactory solution.

one solution is to create a copy of song before play/stream and delete it on completion but i don't think that is a good solution.

please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not at a computer with visual studio on it at the moment, but look at this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for File.Open
Try changing this line:

```
using (var video = File.Open(_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

to

```
using (var video = File.Open(_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
```

See if that helps.